# Go plugin core dumps when using go routines and variables

Tags: go, crash, coredump

I am unable to use variables inside my go routine started in a go plugin.
The following code is an example of what I am trying to do.

The code

```
// Can be an non-empty struct as well
var channel = make(chan string) 
log.Println(channel) 
go func(ch chan string) { 
    log.Println(ch) 
}(channel)
```

crahes with a coredump when executed in a go plugin on darwin.

-Yes Go plugins work on darwin: http://prntscr.com/iq8czy

Comment: This isn't really the place to post bugs about a Go implementation. The issue tracker should be sufficient.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Can you share your code on pastebin or somewhere ? I'd like to test it on my machine if possible

Comment: @JimB thought it might help. I spent days on this just to figure out that the plugin thing is broken (for me and some other guy on github)

Comment: @RayfenWindspear nope they work fine on darwin. Except for... this issue.

Just use go 1.10 and try again

Comment: Yup, it 'sploded... `runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.goexit called from 0xc42007c0c0`

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Yup, yet still some people downvote for no reason :/

Comment: It's downvoted because bug reports are off topic. The support ticket is sufficient.

Comment: it seems a little unfair to OP to down vote when they would have been unclear whether a bug or programming error when asking

Comment: @RayfenWindspear The thing is, I would never expect this to be an actual bug in go, I'd search on stack overflow, and I had this exact question yesterday, which I deleted to create this self-solving question so that others actually find the reason why their code fails. (I fixed up the main post now, so it doesn't look like a bugreport)

Comment: @WebweaverD which is the reason I, myself, did not do any downvoting. It had one from someone else, which I deemed enough given that there is technically no specific documentation or guidelines that say this sort of bug is off topic... yet it is. Hence the explanation I gave. It really should be in the guidelines though.

Answer (score 0):

I recently reported this issue to golang: [Issue related to go plugin crashes](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24351)

This only appears to be the case on darwin (OS X).